# Comparing two text array columns using % and ordering by number of matches

Tags: postgresql

I have a user table that contains a "skills" column which is a text array. Given some input array, I would like to find all the users whose skills % one or more of the entries in the input array, and order by number of matches (according to the % operator from pg_trgm).

For example, I have Array['java', 'ruby', 'postgres'] and I want users who have these skills ordered by the number of matches (max is 3 in this case).

I tried `unnest()` with an `inner join`. It looked like I was getting somewhere, but I still have no idea how I can capture the count of the matching array entries. Any ideas on what the structure of the query may look like?

**Edit:** Details:

Here is what my `programmers` table looks like:

```
id |            skills             
----+-------------------------------
  1 | {javascript,rails,css}
  2 | {java,"ruby on rails",adobe}
  3 | {typescript,nodejs,expressjs}
  4 | {auth0,c++,redis}
```

where `skills` is a text array.

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT * FROM programmers, unnest(skills) skill_array(x)
    INNER JOIN unnest(Array['ruby', 'node']) search(y)
    ON skill_array.x % search.y;
```

which outputs the following:

```
id |            skills             |       x       |    y    
----+-------------------------------+---------------+---------
  2 | {java,"ruby on rails",adobe}  | ruby on rails | ruby
  3 | {typescript,nodejs,expressjs} | nodejs        | node
  3 | {typescript,nodejs,expressjs} | expressjs     | express
```

*Assuming pg_trgm is enabled.

Comment: I know it's a pain, but can you show us your table structure and the query you've already tried?

Comment: @Brad Updated the question. I should've included everything from the start but my workspace was a mess and I didn't want to dig through my psql sessions 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For an exact match between the user skills and the searched skills, you can proceed like this :**

1. You put the searched skills in the *target_skills* text array
2. You filter the users from the table *user_table* whose *user_skills* array has at least one common element with the *target_skills* array by using the `&&` operator
3. For each of the selected users, you select the common skills by using `unnest` and `INTERSECT`, and you calculate the number of these common skills
4. You order the result by the number of common skills `DESC`

In this process, the users with skill "ruby" will be selected for the target skill "ruby", but not the users with skill "ruby on rails".

This process can be implemented as follow :

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.user_skills
     , inter.skills
FROM user_table AS u
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    (   SELECT array(   SELECT unnest(u.user_skills)
                        INTERSECT
                        SELECT unnest(target_skills)
                    ) AS skills
    ) AS inter
WHERE u.user_skills && target_skills
ORDER BY array_length(inter.skills, 1) DESC
```

or with this variant :

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.user_skills
     , array_agg(t_skill) AS inter_skills
FROM user_table AS u
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(target_skills) AS t_skill
WHERE u.user_skills && array[t_skill]
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.user_skills
ORDER BY array_length(inter_skills, 1) DESC
```

This query can be accelerated by creating a GIN index on the *user_skills* column of the *user_table*.

**For a partial match between the user skills and the target skills** (ie the users with skill "ruby on rails" must be selected for the target skill "ruby"), you need to use the pattern matching operator `LIKE` or the `regular expression`, but it is not possible to use them with text arrays, so you need first to transform your *user_skills* text array into a simple text with the function `array_to_string`. The query becomes :

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.user_skills
     , array_agg(t_skill) AS inter_skills
FROM user_table AS u
CROSS JOIN unnest(target_skills) AS t_skill
WHERE array_to_string(u.user_skills, ' ') ~ t_skill
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.user_skills
ORDER BY array_length(inter_skills, 1) DESC ;
```

Then you can accelerate the queries by creating the following `GIN` (or `GiST`) index :

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS user_skills ;
CREATE INDEX user_skills
  ON user_table
  USING gist (array_to_string(user_skills, ' ') gist_trgm_ops) ;    -- gin_trgm_ops and gist_trgm_ops indexes are compliant with the LIKE operator and the regular expressions
```

In any case, managing the skills as text will ever fail if there are typing errors or if the skills list is not normalized.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. How would the && filtering part change to match with % from pg_trgm? In other words, I want a special && that does partial matching.

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate that. I posted an answer adapting your pre-edit query by creating a new &&% operator that matches with %. Is that approach maybe worse than the one you added for partial matching?

Comment: I have simplified my answer for the partial match solution. Then, you can simply replace the ~ operator of the regular expression in the WHERE clause of the query by the % operator of the pg_trgm module, everything should work the same way. The solution you propose in your answer may not be "indexable", ie creating an index to accelerate your queries, because when the index is created, the right argument of your operator &&% is not yet known, it is only known at the query execution step (to be confirmed).

Answer (score 0):

I accepted **Edouard**'s answer, but I thought I'd show something else I adapted from it.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partial_and_and(list1 TEXT[], list2 TEXT[])
   RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
   SELECT EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM unnest(list1) x, unnest(list2) y
       WHERE x % y
   );
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Then create the operator:

```sql
CREATE OPERATOR &&% (
    LEFTARG = TEXT[],
    RIGHTARG = TEXT[],
    PROCEDURE = partial_and_and,
    COMMUTATOR = &&%
);
```

And finally, the query:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.skills, array_agg(t_skill) AS inter_skills
FROM programmers AS p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(Array['ruby', 'java']) AS t_skill
WHERE p.skills &&% array[t_skill]
GROUP BY p.id, p.skills
ORDER BY array_length(inter_skills, 1) DESC;
```

This will output an error saying column 'inter_skills' does not exist (not sure why), but oh well point is the query seems to work. All credit goes to **Edouard**.